Nifi python processor cannot create Relationships in configure processor UI
I created a Python Nifi Processor just as in the standard python documentation. This is NOT an ExecuteScript processor. I am able to load the python processor but when I click the Configure Processor -> Relationships tab, I see no relationships there.  This renders the Python processor useless. We cannot forward the resulting flowfile to any other downstream processors.  The Error I get when trying to do so is -> "WriteHelloWorld' does not support any relationships.
The basic example in the documentation that I am using as is, does return FlowFileTransformResult with success relationship but this being a scripted language, NIFI may not know in advance what the relationships may be. Am I missing any steps in defining relationships for python processors?
Created python processor in Nifi
Loaded it
Tried to connected it to PutFile processor
Got message stating that my Python processor does not define relationships.

To answer this question, it would be helpful to describe in detail all the steps required the reproduce the problem. Share any relevant code snippets and/or UI state.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems that the existing custom python processors shipped with version 2 for Nifi do not work as expected.


Add an existing processor to the Nifi



Try to connect it to PutFile or  sink, you will see a dialog stating that the processor does not support relationships.    How do we connect existing processors shipped with Nifi 2 to downstream processors?   Try using ChunkDocument or ParseDocument processors. Please let me know if that works for you.   I am using Python 10 here.

